# Java 8 stream Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> return map values if root map key contains

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of maps:

`Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> rootMap`

and I want to return the rootMap values `Map<String, Integer>` if `rootMap` key contains `stringValue` using stream.

I tried:

```
rootMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(stringValue)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

but I get `Map<Object, Object>` instead of `Map<String, Integer>`

Update #1

```
// it's a class with one field and a helper method
// @Data is a Lombok annotation
@Data
public class A {

    public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> rootMap;

    public Map<String, Integer> getValuesByKey(String stringValue) {
        return rootMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(stringValue)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you declare your Map without generics? 
The reason is probably this

Comment: @DmitriiB I have ```rootMap``` with data with ```<String, Map<String, Integer>>``` types. I get the values from it just fine, but when I'm using filter I get ```<Object, Object>```

Comment: How do you initialize that Map? I've tried your filter and it returns `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

Comment: Btw. why do you even use a stream here? Just use `rootMap.get(stringValue)` to get a `Map<String, Integer>` value assigned to `stringValue` key.

Comment: @Amongalen I'm afraid I can't use ```.get()``` because I need to check if the ```rootMap``` key contains ```stringValue``` first and then get the values.

Comment: You mean `if(rootMap.contains(stringValue)) ... = rootMap.get(stringValue)`? Iterating over the whole entry set is wasteful when time of retrieving from map is constant.

Comment: @Amongalen see ```Update #1``` for what I have.

Comment: @Amongalen I mean I need to make sure ```stringValue``` is in ```rootMap``` KEY before getting rootMap values.

Comment: Currently your filter does exactly the same as `.get()` (expect that it return a wrong type). Please update the question and explain why you can't use a `.get()` method (which returns a value if it exists in the map).

Comment: @Amongalen the ```stringValue``` is the part of the ```rootMap``` Key String value, so I need to check if it ```rootMap``` key contains the ```stringValue``` (if string is in key String value) before getting ```rootMap``` values. I'm not sure if ```.get()``` does this check and that's why I'm using ```stream()```

Comment: Currently your code returns `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` (as long as you initialize `rootMap` as a generic map and don't use a raw type), not sure how you imagine converting it to a single map.

Comment: Perhaps, you want to use `.map(Map.Entry::getValue).findAny().orElse(…)` instead of `.collect(…)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your expression:

```
rootMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(stringValue))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Here is your goal:

> and I want to return the rootMap values Map<String, Integer> if
> rootMap key contains stringValue using stream.

Recall that map keys must be unique.  You can't have more than one `Map.Entry` of the same instance with the same key.  Therefore, you can obtain the `Map<String, Integer>` corresponding to the key in `rootMap` whose value is `stringValue` as follows:

```
rootMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(stringValue))
    .map(e -> e.getValue())
    .findAny()
    .get();
```

To defend against an error in the case that the key does not exist in `rootMap` you can use this version:

```
rootMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(stringValue))
    .map(e -> e.getValue())
    .findAny()
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

Comment: `rootMap` already contains unique keys, and `toMap` Collector can indeed produce empty result, so probably there is nothing to worry about

Comment: Agree.  My post is merely in response to the notion that a collector is not necessary.